# Ansible fails to connect to host on some plays

Tags: ansible

I have a very simple play that I'm having a lot of issues to get the run correctly. I keep getting an SSH unreachable error when it is run. I'm getting this on 2 separate machines in different environments (although built from the same images) These are Debian 9 boxes.

Play is to simply update an internal mirror server.

```
- name: Update Mirror Servers
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
  -  name: Run Update
     shell: "sudo apt-mirror"

  -  name: Change Permissions
     file:
       path: /var/apt-mirror
       state: directory
       recurse: yes
       mode: '0755'
```

This is being run from Ansible AWX just in case that makes any difference.

Error is as follows.

```
"unreachable": true,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf\r\ndebug2: checking match for 'final all' host x.x.x.x originally x.x.x.x\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'\r\ndebug2: match not found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]\r\ndebug1: configuration requests final Match pass\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname x.x.x.x is address\r\ndebug1: re-parsing configuration\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf\r\ndebug2: checking match for 'final all' host x.x.x.x originally x.x.x.x\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'\r\ndebug2: match found\r\ndebug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config\r\ndebug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]\r\ndebug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4\r\ndebug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 10035\r\ndebug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent\r\ndebug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe\r\ndebug2: Control master terminated unexpectedly\r\nShared connection to x.x.x.x closed.",
    "changed": false
```

I've tried adding the ansible_ssh_user and ansible_ssh_pass as variables on the group these machines are in.
I am able to run ping successfully etc.

Identity added: /tmp/awx_187_x0lo965h/artifacts/187/ssh_key_data

```
(/tmp/awx_187_x0lo965h/artifacts/187/ssh_key_data)
SSH password: 
BECOME password[defaults to SSH password]: 
redacted | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

I'm sure it is probably something minor that I'm missing in config somewhere. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks,

Kam

Comment: Hi....WC to SO! Kindly go through the link https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example